# Core Data: observing nested properties

Tags: cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing

I have an entity Category in my Core Data model. Category has a to-many relation to Article. Article has a property read, which is a boolean.

I want to observe the number of unread articles (so I can display it in the title).

A first approach would be something like:

```
    [self.category addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"articles.@sum.read" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

But this doesn't work. I can observe the articles collection to see if something is added, and observe all of the elements individually. I can get this working, but I wonder if there is an easier way. Any hints?

(This might be a duplicate of [Using KVO to observe changes to a property on an object inside a collection in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691621/using-kvo-to-observe-changes-to-a-property-on-an-object-inside-a-collection-in-o), but I still think there should be a better way).

Answer (score 0):

How *precisely* do you need to know what changed and when it changed? If your requirements are very simple, you can listen to the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notification and check the `userInfo` for `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`. Those objects will return the changes through their `-changedValues` method.

How do things get added to the `articles` collection? It probably easiest to simply hook in there directly in stead of using KVO.

Comment: I've found that changedValues returns the old values when responding to that notification.